# Div structure with percent height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build certain structure on page.
[image]

Main div (.row) with 400px height, two child divs (columns col-md-6), and five inner divs: two with 50% of parent height, three with 33% of parent height. And I don't get how to implement this. Could you recommend the best solution?

P.S. I'm using bootstrap3.

UPDATE: Added code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="ember828" class="ember-view bar-category-box">
    </div>
    <div id="ember829" class="ember-view bar-category-box">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="ember830" class="ember-view bar-category-box">
    </div>
    <div id="ember831" class="ember-view bar-category-box">
    </div>
    <div id="ember832" class="ember-view bar-category-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the html/css you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox**, or with combination of bootstrap and flexbox [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/456/)

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #73FCD6;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #965504;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box">Content</div>
    <div class="box">Content</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box">Content</div>
    <div class="box">Content</div>
    <div class="box">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well he doesn't have to.

Comment: I have a thought that it can be solved with bootstrap, so I added that tag.

Comment: There is a much shorter answer in this topic that works for me. Could you explain what benefits of using flexbox in general or just in my case? Your snippet also looks exactly what I want.

Comment: @Crabar Then I suggest you update your question saying exactly that

Comment: @Crabar Flexbox is the new modern way to do layout, simple as that, and doesn't suffer from old issues that floats and inline-block do.

Comment: @Crabar Also, flexbox gives you many things what bootstrap does, particular in this case, without the need of a library and a bunch of classes on every other element.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks. I will try both ways. Unfortunately I cannot accept both answers. So I just vote both and accept one of them.

Comment: @LGSon Well said. I couldn't have put it better myself.

Answer (score 4):

Since the .row is fixed at 400px height, you can give whats inside the same height:

```
.row > .col-md-6 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

then for each div inside .col-md-6 you give the height you need:

```
.row > .col-md-6 .half {
    height: 50%;
}
.row > .col-md-6 .third {
    height: 33.33%;
}
```

This should work.
And even if the parent .row div height changed the inside should adapt.